# Regular expression to match specific filename pattern containing underscores

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that would match files of this pattern:

`Id_Name_processID_timestamp_logName.txt`

Example of filename:  `abcd_Service_11234_15112013_Log.txt`

I don't need perfect matching something that would match `anything_anything_anything_anything_anything.txt` would work for me.

I haven't tried anything just lost time starring at this [Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for quite a long time, i don t know where to start :(.

Comment: *I haven't tried anything!* I suggest you to try, and come with a problem.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I think i pointed out correctly that i don't know where to start from. there are tons of regex questions here that don't have a starting point. If you can suggest a better resource that would be grat but i don t see why you downvoted

Comment: I'd really help if you tried something. May be completely wrong. but some effort to show us? and for downvote "Questions can be downvoted if shows no effort or research"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to this site: http://regexpal.com/

Put `abcd_Service_11234_15112013_Log.txt` in the lower box.

Start writing your rexex on the top box, until it matches (it's a simple one, really, chars, underscore, rinse and repeat) ... You'll be ok ...

Comment: Yup, start off matching the first character and keep building it up until it matches the whole string. If it stops matching, you know you've done something wrong.

Comment: then upvote :) ... in any case ... took me like 90 seconds to come up with a solution, which I'm impressed with, since I didn't touch regex for a couple of years now ... My solution has 29 chars in it ... If only the OP would have tried solving this on his own ...

Answer (score 0):

My regex, a short simple one.

^\w+_\w+.txt

Edit: 
I do agree with the 1st answer: You really need to try something on your own but that website must be the least userfriendly page on regex. You get my answer out of sympathy ;)

Comment: This is not what OP needs. `\w+.txt` itself enough in that case

Comment: Yes that would do too. But that would match a sentence without the underscores wich i belive is even further from what the OP wanted. If he needs an exact match on number of segments he can replace the first + with a {n}

Comment: I think you should read the question again. OP don't want to match `anything_anything_anything_anything_anything`

Comment: I read what he say the other way around :) So to me that reads he wants to match anything_anything_anything_anything_anything.txt

Comment: sympathy ... it'll be the end of us ... what's your problem with that website? I find it highly useful ...